# Problema al rellenar ComboBox en Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, combobox

Ya habia cargado una pregunta similar pero no me funciono.
La idea es un programa de recetas. Tengo una clase llamada "Insumo", se dan de alta varios insumos, y luego esos insumos (uno o varios) se cargan en un "Plato" (otra clase).
Los insumos los almaceno en un Array, y los Platos contienen Array de Insumos.
Esto se define en la clase Resto.

Ahora bien, pude crear la interfaz grafica mediante [windowbuilder](/questions/tagged/windowbuilder) para llenar generar mis insumos y cargar el Array. pero levantar la interfaz de los platos el Array de Insumo me da error. Es decir. Quiero mostrarlos en un JcomboBox, y me tira error. Tambien puede ser un Jlist, de hecho, en la interfaz de platos, a medida que los voy generando los voy mostrando en un Jlist, como muestro abajo.

Quisiera saber cual es la mejor forma, si mostrarlos en un combo, o en un jlist.
y como solucionar este error. (Me dice que debo cambiar el tipo que devuelve el método devolverInsumos dentro de la clase Resto).

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo!

```
public class Insumo {

private static int INCREMENTAR_CODIGO = 0;
    
private int codigo;
private String descripcion;
private int precio;

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}
public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}
public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String toString() {
    return codigo +"-"+descripcion;
}

public Insumo(String descripcion, int precio) {
    this.codigo = ++INCREMENTAR_CODIGO;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.precio = precio;
}
    
}

package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Resto {

private static ArrayList<Insumo> insumos = new ArrayList<Insumo>();
private static ArrayList<Plato> platos = new ArrayList<Plato>();
private static ArrayList<Mesa> mesas = new ArrayList<Mesa>();
    
public void addInsumo(String descripcion, int precio) {
    insumos.add(new Insumo(descripcion, precio));       
}

public int largoArray (){
    return insumos.size();
}

public ArrayList<Insumo> devolverInsumos(){
    return insumos;
}
        
public void addPlatoComun(String nombre) {
    platos.add(new PlatoComun(nombre));
}

public void addPlatoEspecial(String nombre) {
    platos.add(new PlatoEspecial(nombre));
}

public ArrayList<Plato> devolverPlatos(){
    return platos;
}

public void addMesa(){
    mesas.add(new Mesa());
}

public ArrayList<Mesa> devolverMesas(){
    return mesas;
}

public ArrayList<Mesa> devolverMesasDisponibles(){
    ArrayList<Mesa> disponibles = new ArrayList<Mesa>();
    
    for(Mesa m: mesas) {
        if(m.isDisponible()){
            disponibles.add(m);
        }
    }
    
    return disponibles;
}

public void abrirMesa(Mesa m){
    m.cambiarAbierta();
}



public void agregarPlatosAMesa(Mesa m, ArrayList<Plato> p){
    m.agregarPlatos(p);
}

public void agregarInsumosAPlato(Plato p, ArrayList<Insumo> i){
    p.agregarInsumos(i);
}

public void addInsumo(Insumo ins) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

}
```

Aca está el error del JComboBox

```
package vista;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import model.Insumo;
import model.PlatoEspecial;
import model.Resto;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JList;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

public class Interface_Plato extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private JTextField txt_codigo;
private JTextField txt_desc;
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
private Resto resto;


public Interface_Plato(Resto r) {
    resto = r;
    
    setTitle("Alta de Platos");
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][grow]", "[][][][][][grow]"));
    
        JLabel lblCodigo = new JLabel("Codigo:");
        contentPanel.add(lblCodigo, "cell 0 0,alignx trailing");
    
    
        txt_codigo = new JTextField();
        contentPanel.add(txt_codigo, "cell 1 0,alignx left");
        txt_codigo.setColumns(10);
    
    
        JLabel lblDescripcion = new JLabel("Descripcion:");
        contentPanel.add(lblDescripcion, "cell 0 1,alignx trailing");
    
    
        txt_desc = new JTextField();
        contentPanel.add(txt_desc, "cell 1 1,alignx left");
        txt_desc.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblInsumo = new JLabel("Insumo:");
        contentPanel.add(lblInsumo, "cell 0 2,alignx trailing");
                

        JComboBox<Insumo> cb_insumos = new JComboBox<Insumo>();
        contentPanel.add(cb_insumos, "cell 1 2,growx"); 
        DefaultComboBoxModel<Insumo> modelito = new 
DefaultComboBoxModel<Insumo>();
        cb_insumos.setModel(modelito);
//  llenar JList con los Insumos
        cb_insumos.addItem(r.devolverInsumos());
        modelito.addElement(r.devolverInsumos());
        for (int i=0;i<r.largoArray(); ) {
            cb_insumos.addItem(r.devolverInsumos(i));
        }
        
//problema para cargar el jlist con objetos                     
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Agregar Insumo al Plato");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(btnNewButton, "cell 1 3");
        
        JLabel lblEsPlatoEspecial = new JLabel("Tipo de Plato");
        contentPanel.add(lblEsPlatoEspecial, "cell 0 4");
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnComn = new JRadioButton("Com\u00FAn");
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnComn);
        contentPanel.add(rdbtnComn, "flowx,cell 1 4");
    
    
        JList<Insumo> list = new JList<Insumo>();
        
        contentPanel.add(list, "cell 1 4");     
    
        contentPanel.add(list, "cell 1 5,grow");
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnEspecial = new JRadioButton("Especial");
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnEspecial);
        contentPanel.add(rdbtnEspecial, "cell 1 4");
    
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        JButton okButton = new JButton("Confirmar");
        
            
        JButton btnCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
        btnCancelar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dispose();
            }
            });
        
            buttonPane.add(btnCancelar);
            okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        
            JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    dispose();
                }
            });
}

}
```

Y así genero mis Insumos

```
package vista;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import model.Insumo;
import model.Resto;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JList;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Interface_Insumo extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private JTextField txt_Codigo;
private JTextField txt_Nombre;
private Resto resto;
private Insumo insumo;


JList<Insumo> list = new JList<Insumo>();
private JTextField txt_Precio;
DefaultListModel<Insumo> model = new DefaultListModel<Insumo>();

public Interface_Insumo(Resto r) {
    setTitle("Alta de Insumos");
    resto = r;
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[10px][grow][grow]", "[10px][][][][][][][]"));
    
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.add(panel, "cell 0 0,alignx left,aligny top");
    
    
        JLabel lblCrearNuevoInsumo = new JLabel("Crear nuevo insumo");
        lblCrearNuevoInsumo.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Light", Font.BOLD, 18));
        contentPanel.add(lblCrearNuevoInsumo, "cell 1 0");
    
    
        JLabel lblCodigo = new JLabel("Codigo:");
        contentPanel.add(lblCodigo, "cell 0 1,alignx trailing");
    
       //Igual q la linea de abajo pero paso todo en 1 linea
        
        txt_Codigo = new JTextField();
        txt_Codigo.setEditable(false);
        contentPanel.add(txt_Codigo, "cell 1 1,alignx left");
                
        JLabel lblDescripcion = new JLabel("Nombre:");
        contentPanel.add(lblDescripcion, "cell 0 2,alignx trailing");
            
        txt_Nombre = new JTextField();
        contentPanel.add(txt_Nombre, "cell 1 2,alignx left");
        txt_Nombre.setColumns(10);
        
        JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
        contentPanel.add(scrollBar, "flowx,cell 1 5");
    
/*/
 * Creo y defino el modelo de la lista de insumos que se hará visible. */

        list.setModel(model);
//          
        contentPanel.add(list, "cell 1 5");
                    
        JLabel lblPrecio = new JLabel("Precio:");
        contentPanel.add(lblPrecio, "cell 0 3,alignx trailing");
        
        txt_Precio = new JTextField();
        contentPanel.add(txt_Precio, "cell 1 3,alignx left");
        txt_Precio.setColumns(10);
                
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
// Creo el obtjeto insumo dentro del array
        
        JButton okButton = new JButton("Confirmar");
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    int precio = Integer.parseInt(txt_Precio.getText());
                    Insumo ins = new Insumo(txt_Nombre.getText(), precio);

// Inserto el Array? o el objeto individual?
//                      ArrayList<Insumo> insumosd = new ArrayList<Insumo>();
//                      insumosd.add(ins);
//                      resto.addInsumo(insumo);                            
                    resto.addInsumo(ins); // <-- Forma Correcta ??
//  validacion                      
                    System.out.printf(txt_Codigo.getText()+" "+ txt_Nombre.getText());
                    
((DefaultListModel<Insumo>)list.getModel()).addElement(ins);
                    System.out.print(resto.devolverInsumos());

                }
            });
            okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        
        
            JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    dispose();
                                            
                }
            });
            
            cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
        
}

}
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu mensaje de error?